# Best deployment strategy for Python google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, deployment

I wonder if there are any best practices/patterns for deploying python apps on Google app engine specifically Django. The best practice should be combination of existing best practices viz. Fabric, Paver, Buildout etc. Also please share best practice patterns for developing (I could not get virtualenv running with Django and Django App engine helper)

Comment: I haven't had any problems with django 1.1.1 and the helper with virtualenv on OSX.  What problems did you have?

Comment: Mostly some modules missing like unittest.

Answer (score 2):

For many projects, you shouldn't need any deployment process at all. If you're using App Engine Patch or Django-Nonrel, they should take care of everything for you.

For other needs, check out [this article on buildout](http://code.google.com/p/typhoonae/wiki/AppEngineBuildout) and [this set of buildout recipes](http://code.google.com/p/appfy/).