# Custom plugins for Google App Engine using python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sass

How would i go about installing a plugin for python (google app engine) ? lets say i want to use this: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyScss ? Can i use easy_install and how? I'm a bit new and can't seem to find any real info about it.

Thanks.

Comment: If it is a python-pure module you can just put it in the root of your project.

Comment: root of what? please be more descriptive. GOogle app engine actual aplication "test5" or python27 folder or google sdk folder, I dont know.

Comment: At the root of your own app engine application

Comment: Ok I downloaded the pysass.tar.gz, extracted it, and install it running the "setup.py install command?" What do I do now, I believe this now install on my local machine not the GAE SDK?

Comment: No, just put the folder 'scss' in the root of your own app engine project

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer to include it using [buildout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759814/buildout-google-app-engine), otherwise you have to unpack it into the folder that will be uploaded to App Engine.

Note that only python works on App Engine, the optional C extension in pyScss won't work.