# How to install python package to Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

https://github.com/yoavaviram/python-amazon-simple-product-api
states that it is compatile with GAE. But How could I install it to gae?
GAE allow limited libraries via app.yaml like below
    libraries:
    - name: jinja2
    version: latest

So how could I install it? It also requires bottlenose as far as I know pip install does not work right?

Comment: See also: [How do I manage third-party Python libraries with Google App Engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863557/how-do-i-manage-third-party-python-libraries-with-google-app-engine-virtualenv)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For most python libraries, you simply copy it into your GAE project.  This one looks like it'll work if you just copy the amazon folder into your project.