# How to set up Eclipse-Pydev for Google app engine development

Tags: google-app-engine, pydev, eclipse-juno

I am trying to use PyDev on Eclipse Juno to create a GoogleAppEngine project. I am very new to Python and AppEngine. So PyDev asks me for `Google App Engine Directory` which apparently is where the `appcfg.py` file is. I have already installed the GAE and it works well with IDLE (I am using Mac).

Has anyone set this up successfully? Basically, I don't know where the directory is. I am of course assuming that's the only problem.

I have already tried to find `appcfg.py` from the terminal using `find . -name appcfg.py`, `mdfind -name appcfg.py`, `whereis appcfg.py`. But so far no success.

Comment: See my answer [here][1] on an old thread.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863557/how-do-i-manage-third-party-python-libraries-with-google-app-engine-virtualenv/4863970#4863970

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

> Enter the following:
>
> /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/ 
>   GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/

For more details, see [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine-python/xZQusVOJAJw).

Answer (score -1):

Just to very quickly update this for Mavericks, I tried this, but Eclipse wouldn't see the "GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle" as a directory. It's a little weird, but I used "Quick Look" ("Ctl-Click, Quick Look", not just pressing the space bar) in the Open dialog box to open the Eclipse bundle, and then again for the .bundle directory. You have to actually click "Quick Look"; double-clicking doesn't seem to work. For some reason it then saw the bundle directory as a directory and allowed me to open it. After that, I just navigated to the directory @payala mentioned and it found all the files it needed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thanks for the condescending lecture, @popovitsj. I was neither critiquing nor requesting clarification from anyone - I was merely trying to be *helpful*. But if that's not adequate or approved, then fine - I'll simply refrain from contributing. I have neither the time nor inclination to be lectured or for my contribution summarily deleted.