# Google App Engine Python SDK for Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, google-app-engine, sdk

I am trying to develop my first GAE app with Python on Eclipse, from [this](http://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/google-app-engine-python-hello-world-example-using-eclipse/) tutorial I am sent [here](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/download) I do the instal. When I go into Eclipse, new -> project -> PyDev -> PyDev Google App Engine Program, I name it and then in the next window it asks for the Google App Engine Directory, so I choose

```
/Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.7.1.
```

and it tells me "Invalid Google App Engine directory. Did not find: appcfg.py in

```
/Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.7.1"
```

and When I dive into that directory, which should have what I need I see appengine-java-sdk-1.7.7.1 and no python.

In addition when I use the blue google circle in the toolbar to create an app it creates it with only java files.

In further addition I've seen in questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533981/how-to-set-up-eclipse-pydev-for-google-app-engine-development?rq=1) one people suggest looking for

```
/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/ GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/
```

only I apparently don't have that anywwhere on my computer, even though I do have the GAE launcher installed.

Long story short, how do I get the GAE python sdk for eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the google plugin is only for Java so it is useless for Python development... Yes I know it is sad, I was disapointed as well.

Then the second link you gave is wrong and I don't know where you got it but if you go on your first link, section 3. Google App Engine SDK Python, you will go [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Python), which is the good link. For Linux, you end up with a zip file that you simply need to extract and you will find the appcfg.py file in it.

The fisrt link you gave is the one I followed and is very well explain. Keep looking.