# How do i import rpy2--Another libs/modules to Google App Engine project

Tags: python, google-app-engine, rpy2

Here is [rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2_documentation.html).

I'd install using 'easy_install rpy2'.

Please explain me "step by step".

Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only content in the application folder will be uploaded.

So you need to just take the relevant folder and put it in your app engine project folder. Just like you would import your own modules. It will then be availble to your app engine app.

So install the thing you want to install, take it's install directory and copy it into your app engine applications directory. This is generic, it's not specific to the package you have linked to.

This is a similar question: [How do I manage third-party Python libraries with Google App Engine? (virtualenv? pip?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863557/how-do-i-manage-third-party-python-libraries-with-google-app-engine-virtualenv)

Note that if it's not pure python (i.e. has C components) it won't work on app engine.

GAE note:

> You can use any pure Python third party libraries in your Google App Engine application. In order to use a third party library, simply include the files in your application's directory, and they will be uploaded with your application when you deploy it to our system. You can import the files as you would any other Python files with your application.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/commontasks#thirdparty

Comment: I'd try following "How do I manage third-party Python libraries with Google App Engine? (virtualenv? pip?)" but didn't work. I don't know what wrong? Are you explain me step by step following that.

Comment: install your module. Copy it's install folder to your app engine folder (or use a more sophisticated system if preferred with simlinks etc) and then you can call it from your application. I'm not sure how much more "step by step" I can make it.

Comment: -proj
 -rpy2 <- copy from Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rpy2-2.3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg
  -__init__.py
  -robjects
   -__init__.py
   -robject.py

app.yaml
 - url: rpy2
   static_dir: rpy2

proj.py
import robjects.robjects

"ImportError: No module named robjects.robject"

Comment: it's not going to work anyway, there is C code in rpy2 which app engine does not support.

Comment: Are you know python lib include ARIMA function what working for GAE