# What are the "imports" for GAE OAuth2.0?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm following [this](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#authenticationuriparameters) tutorial to learn how to get OAuth2.0 login onto my site, and I'm having some problems. My site is registered on GAE and I have my client ID. I also `pip install`ed `google-api-python-client`. However, I don't know what to import into my project. I have two pages in my application. One that handles authorization and one that actually has the page.

authorize.py

```
import cgi, webapp2
from google.appengine.api import users

LOGIN_PAGE_HTML="""\
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="submit" method="post" action="/AuthorizeUser"/>
  </body>
</html>
"""

class LoginPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.response.write(LOGIN_PAGE_HTML)

class AuthorizeUser(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    state = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits)for x in xrange(32))
    session['state'] = state
    response = make_response('/LandingPage',
                             CLIENT_ID='MY ID',
                             STATE=state
                             APPLICATION_NAME='Summit Tech Help'))
    if request.args.get('state','') != session['state']:
      response = make_response(json.dumps('Invalid state parameter.'), 401)
      response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
      return response






application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/',LoginPage),
    ('/AuthorizeUser',AuthorizeUser),
], debug=True)
```

landing.py

```
import cgi, webapp2
from google.appengine.api import mail

LANDING_PAGE_HTML="""\
<html>
    <body>
      <p>test</p>
    </body>
</html>

"""

class LandingPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write(LANDING_PAGE_HTML)

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
('LandingPage',LandingPage),
],debug=True)
```

My `app.yaml` has '-url: /.*' set to `script:authorize.application`

Any help would be much appreciated!

~Carpetfizz

Comment: You are trying to add a third party library (OAuth2.0) to Appengine. May be answers to this questions can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863557/how-do-i-manage-third-party-python-libraries-with-google-app-engine-virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

to use a 3rd party module you need to import it in your app, if that's what you meant to ask, 
also do check this link to use [external libraries in gae.](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27)

You can check this [example app for using Oauth2.0 in GAE](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/wiki/SampleApps#OAuth_2.0_Samples)