# How to install lxml on Mac to be used with GAE?

Tags: python, macos, google-app-engine, python-2.7, lxml

I know that lxml 2.3 is supported by GAE with Python 2.7, but it doesn't work locally on Mac (`No module named lxml`). So, I've download [lxml 2.3](http://lxml.de/files/lxml-2.3.tgz). What should I do then to have it installed? I've tried to copy `lxml-2.3.tgz/lxml-2.3/src/lxml` content to `/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/lxml`, but it didn't help. And I don't use pip, macport etc.

Comment: @Lipis, it is not duplicate, since lxml is part of python 2.7 (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27), but not installed locally.

Comment: yes.. sorry.. my bad..

Comment: Just downloading the source for lxml won't work as it has c based moduile dependencies!  Either find a binary package for or install from source, which involves compiling the package.

Comment: @TimHoffman, what do you mean by 'package'? Is it some dmg file?

Comment: I don't know I don't use a Mac.  But I would imagine a binary package must be available for the Mac. If you don't use macports or pip, then you will have to build from source.

Comment: I would take a look at some of the solutions proposed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863557/how-do-i-manage-third-party-python-libraries-with-google-app-engine-virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

In appengine config, you can point the python path at the virtualenv where you have lxml installed.