# What is the cleanest way to add a directory of third-party packages to the beginning of the Python path?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, python-import, pythonpath

My context is appengine_config.py, but this is really a general Python question.

Given that we've cloned a repo of an app that has an empty directory `lib` in it, and that we populate `lib` with packages by using the command `pip install -r requirements.txt --target lib`, then:

```
dirname ='lib'
dirpath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), dirname)
```

For importing purposes, we can add such a filesystem path to the beginning of the Python path in the following way (we use index 1 because the first position should remain '.', the current directory):

```
sys.path.insert(1, dirpath)
```

However, that won't work if any of the packages in that directory are namespace packages.

To support namespace packages we can instead use:

```
site.addsitedir(dirpath)
```

But that appends the new directory to the *end* of the path, which we don't want in case we need to override a platform-supplied package (such as WebOb) with a newer version.

The solution I have so far is this bit of code which I'd really like to simplify:

```
sys.path, remainder = sys.path[:1], sys.path[1:]
site.addsitedir(dirpath)
sys.path.extend(remainder)
```

Is there a cleaner or more Pythonic way of accomplishing this?

Comment: My current version moves most of this code into an `insertsitedir()` function inside a `vendor.py` module, but otherwise hasn't really changed. Still looking for improvements or simplifications, if any are possible.

Comment: After some more iterations, John Wayne Parrott has packaged up the resulting code: https://github.com/jonparrott/Darth-Vendor

Answer (score 1):

For this answer I assume you know how to use `setuptools` and `setup.py`.

Assuming you would like to use the standard `setuptools` workflow for development, I recommend using this code snipped in your `appengine_config.py`:

```
import os
import sys

if os.environ.get('CURRENT_VERSION_ID') == 'testbed-version':
    # If we are unittesting, fake the non-existence of appengine_config.
    # The error message of the import error is handled by gae and must
    # exactly match the proper string.
    raise ImportError('No module named appengine_config')


# Imports are done relative because Google app engine prohibits
# absolute imports.
lib_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'libs')
# Add every library to sys.path.
if os.path.isdir(lib_dir):
    for lib in os.listdir(lib_dir):
        if lib.endswith('.egg'):
            lib = os.path.join(lib_dir, lib)
            # Insert to override default libraries such as webob 1.1.1.
            sys.path.insert(0, lib)
```

And this piece of code in `setup.cfg`:

```
[develop]
install-dir = libs
always-copy = true
```

If you type `python setup.py develop`, the libraries are downloaded as eggs in the `libs` directory. `appengine_config` inserts them to your path.

We use this at work to include `webob==1.3.1` and internal packages which are all namespaced using our company namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The workflow I have in mind is basically:

`pip install -r requirements.txt -t 'lib'`

Comment: The `appengine_config.py` idea is the same, except that the dependencies in your case are specified in `requirements.txt` instead of in `setup.py`

Comment: `pip install -r requirements.txt -t 'lib'` isn't populating the lib directory with eggs.

Comment: Looks like pip has an -e switch: http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#editable-installs

But it only works with VCS or local file references, so `pip install -e -r requirements.txt -t lib/` fails.

Comment: I've added the missing context to the Q. Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at the answers in the Stack Overflow thread, "[How do I manage third-party Python libraries with Google App Engine? (virtualenv? pip?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863557/how-do-i-manage-third-party-python-libraries-with-google-app-engine-virtualenv)," but for your particular predicament with namespace packages, you're running up against [a long-standing issue I filed against `site.addsitedir`'s behavior of appending to sys.path instead of inserting after the first element](http://bugs.python.org/issue7744). Please feel free to add to that discussion with a link to this use case.

I do want to address something else that you said that I think is misleading:

> My context is appengine_config.py, but this is really a general Python
>   question.

The question actually arises from the limitations of Google App Engine and the inability to install third-party packages, and hence, seeking a workaround. Rather than manually adjusting `sys.path` and using `site.addsitedir`. In *general* Python development, if your code uses these, you're Doing It Wrong.

The [Python Packaging Authority (PyPA) describes the best practices to put third party libraries on your path](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorial.html), which I outline below:

1. Create a virtualenv
2. Mark out your dependencies in your `setup.py` and/or requirements files (see [PyPA's "Concepts and Analyses"](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/technical.html#install-requires-vs-requirements-files))
3. Install your dependencies into the virtualenv with pip
4. Install your project, itself, into the virtualenv with pip and the `-e/--editable` flag.

Unfortunately, Google App Engine is incompatible with virtualenv and with pip. GAE chose to block this toolset in an attempt sandbox the environment. Hence, one must use hacks to work around the limitations of GAE to use additional or newer third party libraries.

If you dislike this limitation and want to use standard Python tooling for managing third-party package dependencies, [other Platform as a Service providers](http://www.quora.com/Other-than-App-Engine-what-Platform-as-a-Service-supports-Python) out there eagerly await your business.

Comment: I've come across this sort of problem before though, such as when building a plugin that needs slightly different dependencies than the system it is plugging into.

You can't use `site.addsitedir()`, because of the append-only behavior, and you can't use `sys.path.insert()` because of namespace packages. Admittedly, in a non-hosted-web-platform context there are a few other avenues to explore (such as forcing the plugged-into-app to upgrade, or getting the plugin to run in it's own process), but the problem is not *quite* unique to GAE.

Comment: I followed up on your suggestion of linking to this Q from the issue tracker: http://bugs.python.org/issue7744#msg226632

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to add to the issue.

Comment: You're welcome. So, any suggestions for actually improving or simplifying the code in my question, given that there *is* no left-append option for `site.addsitedir()`?

Comment: BTW, I edited the closest answer on the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863557/how-do-i-manage-third-party-python-libraries-with-google-app-engine-virtualenv thread to more closely match my current solution.