# Is it posible to use textile 2.2.0 in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, textile

I used [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863557/how-do-i-manage-third-party-python-libraries-with-google-app-engine-virtualenv) to add textile to my Python 2.7 GAE project and found that [`textile 2.2.0`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/textile) depends on [`regex 2014.10.09`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex).

I tried to install `regex 2014.10.09` using the same manual and using pip (and copy it to my project's Lib directory), and none helped. I see that the regex package has `_regex.c` and `_regex.h` files in it, so I guess I cannot use `regex 2014.10.09` in GAE as it's not pure Python...

Is there any way to use `textile 2.2.0` in Google App Engine?

Answer (score 1):

The `regex` dependency is made optional in [this commit](https://github.com/textile/python-textile/commit/7039b39fa902f4513241517d8edbb09cf38f0631).

With [this pull request](https://github.com/textile/python-textile/pull/15) is works in GAE and the tests are passing, thanks to [Radek Czajka](https://github.com/rczajka).