# What is the maintained version of google-app-engine mapreduce for python?

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce

It seems that the latest documentation is this one:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/1-MapReduce
so I assumed that the code in this repo is the latest, is that so?

It seems that in the SDK one can also find a mapreduce lib under  google.appengine.ext.mapreduce.

The issue is that I can't find a working example using either one of them, nor a good installation instructions (just putting the mapreduce dir from the above repo doesn't seem to work). Also running the tests fails.

So before digging in and working through the issues to get it working I wonder if I'm missing something obvious?

Any help will be great.

Answer (score 2):

Got response from the Google team that indeed [this library](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-mapreduce) is maintain.
Indeed the code example was missing but it was added back now and some of the documentation was updated.

The best tutorial I have found is this one:
http://sookocheff.com/series/mapreduce-api/
Now linked from the official documentation.

One thing that wasn't clear to me in the documentation is that in addition to the mapreduce lib which you need to add to your app code, you need also to add the dependencies:
simplejson
cloudstorage
graphy
appengine-pipelines

the code comes with a build.sh which does it on the some code but you need to do it your self if you are adding the mapreduce lib to your code project.

Answer (score 0):

To use the lib you need to add [just this folder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-mapreduce/tree/master/python/src/mapreduce) to your project. Then use these imports:

from mapreduce import base_handler

from mapreduce import mapreduce_pipeline

[This is a good start point.](http://mattfaus.com/2013/10/google-appengine-mapreduce-in-depth/)

Comment: Is that working for you? don't you get exception for not finding simplejson? I've added the simplejson lib + the other libs which the build script installs. even then I need to fix small things vs the documentation. This is what made me wonder if it is up-to-date.

Comment: I was able to include the 3rd party libs using solution suggested at http://stackoverflow.com/a/25564125/1628065