# Django 1.6 settings improperly configured on google app engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

After following the push to deploy tutorial(https://cloud.google.com/tools/repo/push-to-deploy-quickstart) I am receiving the errors below, each time I run the job. My project was a pre-existing django project which I converted using this tutorial https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django

I needed to use third party libraries including django 1.6. After looking at the errors it seems I was only able to include the libraries after using webmaven's code here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25833304/805767 since the django version changed from django-0.96

errors

> ERROR: Failure: ImproperlyConfigured (Requested setting
>   DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must
>   either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call
>   settings.configure() before accessing settings.)
>
> ERROR: Failure: ImproperlyConfigured (Requested setting CACHES, but
>   settings are not configured. You must either define the environment
>   variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before
>   accessing settings.)

stack trace

```
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImproperlyConfigured (Requested setting CACHES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/loader.py", line 414, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/var/jenkins/workspace/myapp_job/lib/rest_framework/tests/test_urlpatterns.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.test import TestCase
  File "/var/jenkins/workspace/myapp_job/lib/django/test/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.test.client import Client, RequestFactory
  File "/var/jenkins/workspace/myapp_job/lib/django/test/client.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout, get_user_model
  File "/var/jenkins/workspace/myapp_job/lib/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.middleware.csrf import rotate_token
  File "/var/jenkins/workspace/myapp_job/lib/django/middleware/csrf.py", line 14, in <module>
    from django.utils.cache import patch_vary_headers
  File "/var/jenkins/workspace/myapp_job/lib/django/utils/cache.py", line 26, in <module>
    from django.core.cache import get_cache
  File "/var/jenkins/workspace/myapp_job/lib/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
    if DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS not in settings.CACHES:
  File "/var/jenkins/workspace/myapp_job/lib/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/var/jenkins/workspace/myapp_job/lib/django/conf/__init__.py", line 47, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CACHES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImproperlyConfigured (Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/loader.py", line 414, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/var/jenkins/workspace/myapp_job/lib/rest_framework/tests/test_validation.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/var/jenkins/workspace/myapp_job/lib/django/db/models/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.db.models.query import Q
  File "/var/jenkins/workspace/myapp_job/lib/django/db/models/query.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.db.models.deletion import Collector
  File "/var/jenkins/workspace/myapp_job/lib/django/db/models/deletion.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.db.models import signals, sql
  File "/var/jenkins/workspace/myapp_job/lib/django/db/models/sql/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.db.models.sql.subqueries import *
  File "/var/jenkins/workspace/myapp_job/lib/django/db/models/sql/subqueries.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.db.models.sql.query import Query
  File "/var/jenkins/workspace/myapp_job/lib/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 22, in <module>
    from django.db.models.sql import aggregates as base_aggregates_module
  File "/var/jenkins/workspace/myapp_job/lib/django/db/models/sql/aggregates.py", line 9, in <module>
    ordinal_aggregate_field = IntegerField()
  File "/var/jenkins/workspace/myapp_job/lib/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 116, in __init__
    self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
  File "/var/jenkins/workspace/myapp_job/lib/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/var/jenkins/workspace/myapp_job/lib/django/conf/__init__.py", line 47, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

appengine_config.py

```
"""This file is loaded when starting a new application instance."""
import os
import site.addsitedir
import sys.path


# os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")
# os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = 'myapp.settings'

dirname = 'lib'
dirpath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), dirname)

# split path after 1st element ('.') so local modules are always found first
sys.path, remainder = sys.path[:1], sys.path[1:]

# add `lib` subdirectory as a site directory, so our `main` module can load
# third-party libraries.
site.addsitedir(dirpath)

# append the rest of the path
sys.path.extend(remainder)
```

app.yaml

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

env_variables:
  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: 'myapp.settings'
```

how do I resolve these errors?

**edit:** added directory structure

```
C:.
│   .gitignore
│   app.yaml
│   appengine_config.py
│   generate_fixtures.py
│   manage.py
│   print.txt
│   README.md
│   requirements.txt
│   __init__.py
├───apps
├───fixtures
├───lib
│   __init__.py
├───myapp
│   app.py
│   app.pyc
│   settings.py
│   settings.pyc
│   urls.py
│   urls.pyc
│   views.py
│   wsgi.py
│   wsgi.pyc
│   wsgi_for_apache.py
│   __init__.py
│   __init__.pyc
```

Comment: What does your directory tree look like?  Where is `settings.py` located?  You are telling the app to look in a directory named 'myapp', which I suspect is not correct.

Comment: myapp is a nickname that I gave the project for this post. the root folder is called myapp and the folder where settings.py resides is also called myapp