# Getting django to use tag

Tags: python, django, pip, imgix

I have installed the django-imgix module from https://github.com/pancentric/django-imgix using the following pip command:

```
pip install -t libs django-imgix
```

This has then created the following structure:
http://screencast.com/t/7rhhdrNLQY

in my settings.py I then added

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'django_imgix',
    )
```

and in the top of my base-template I added

```
{% load imgix_tags %}
```

Now I am getting the following error

```
TemplateSyntaxError: 'imgix_tags' is not a valid tag library: Template library imgix_tags not found, tried google.appengine._internal.django.templatetags.imgix_tags
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

Full stack trace

```
ERROR    2016-07-03 17:29:49,414 webapp2.py:1528] 'imgix_tags' is not a valid tag library: Template library imgix_tags not found, tried google.appengine._internal.django.templatetags.imgix_tags
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/thomasd/Documents/github/myapp/main.py", line 528, in get
    self.response.out.write(template.render(template_page, template_values))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/template.py", line 94, in render
    return t.render(Context(template_dict))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/template.py", line 174, in wrap_render
    return orig_render(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 173, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 794, in render
    bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 807, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 103, in render
    compiled_parent = self.get_parent(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 100, in get_parent
    return get_template(parent)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/loader.py", line 160, in get_template
    template = get_template_from_string(template, origin, template_name)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/loader.py", line 168, in get_template_from_string
    return Template(source, origin, name)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 158, in __init__
    self.nodelist = compile_string(template_string, origin)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 186, in compile_string
    return parser.parse()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 281, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 927, in load
    (taglib, e))
TemplateSyntaxError: 'imgix_tags' is not a valid tag library: Template library imgix_tags not found, tried google.appengine._internal.django.templatetags.imgix_tags
INFO     2016-07-03 17:29:49,511 recording.py:676] Saved; key: __appstats__:089300, part: 71 bytes, full: 15609 bytes, overhead: 0.001 + 0.075; link: http://localhost:8080/_ah/stats/details?time=1467566989338
ERROR    2016-07-03 17:29:49,521 cgi.py:122] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/thomasd/Documents/github/myapp/main.py", line 602, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/thomasd/Documents/github/myapp/main.py", line 598, in main
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/util.py", line 99, in run_wsgi_app
    run_bare_wsgi_app(add_wsgi_middleware(application))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/util.py", line 120, in run_bare_wsgi_app
    for data in result:
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/appstats/recording.py", line 1287, in appstats_wsgi_wrapper
    result = app(environ, appstats_start_response)
  File "/Users/thomasd/Documents/github/myapp/gaesessions/__init__.py", line 448, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, my_start_response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1519, in __call__
    response = self._internal_error(e)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/thomasd/Documents/github/myapp/main.py", line 528, in get
    self.response.out.write(template.render(template_page, template_values))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/template.py", line 94, in render
    return t.render(Context(template_dict))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/template.py", line 174, in wrap_render
    return orig_render(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 173, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 794, in render
    bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 807, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 103, in render
    compiled_parent = self.get_parent(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 100, in get_parent
    return get_template(parent)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/loader.py", line 160, in get_template
    template = get_template_from_string(template, origin, template_name)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/loader.py", line 168, in get_template_from_string
    return Template(source, origin, name)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 158, in __init__
    self.nodelist = compile_string(template_string, origin)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 186, in compile_string
    return parser.parse()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 281, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 927, in load
    (taglib, e))
TemplateSyntaxError: 'imgix_tags' is not a valid tag library: Template library imgix_tags not found, tried google.appengine._internal.django.templatetags.imgix_tags
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the right settings file?

Comment: it is the only settings.py file in my project. So I guess it should be the right one

Comment: Have you added a reference to `/libs` in `appengine_config.py`?

Comment: I used the updated answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863557/how-do-i-manage-third-party-python-libraries-with-google-app-engine-virtualenv. But I am getting the same error

Comment: that is an app engine you have not mentioned whether you use GAE. Anyway, please post the full stack trace

Comment: @e4c5 yes, I am using GAE. I have added the full stack trace

Comment: a quick fix is to move it out of the lib folder

Comment: thanks, it worked. I tried installing other packages with the same result as above. The only solution was to move it out into the root folder of my GAE app