# Google App Engine - Big Query - Python can't find libraries google.cloud

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-bigquery, pydev

I'm building an App Engine project using Python on Ubuntu Linux 16.4 using Eclipse and PyDev.

I'm using the Flask Framework which works fine, what I want to do is connect to Big Query and that's where I am having trouble.

So I have used:

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery
```

To install the Big Query Library and I can see the packages in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

For some reason Eclipse doesn't seem to think the library is registered, I can live with that but when I run my project dev_appserver.py App Engine can't find the library:

[image]

I have this in my Python PyDev:

[image]

It is weird as if I add `from lib.google.cloud import bigquery` PyDev resolves, the dist-packages is in the PyDev path so I don't get why it doesn't pick it up.

You'll also notice I've commented out the `apiclient.discovery` and `oauth2client.client`, I was going to try another way but App Engine complained it couldn't find the `SignedJwtAssertionCredentials` library so I am sure this is all linked and caused by the same problem.

In my `appengine_config.py` I have:

[image: App Engine Config]

Comment: It's because both sdk and the google-cloud package contain  google folder.

Comment: @MattStannard did u find a solution to the problem. I am facing the same.

Answer (score 1):

**(Jun 2021)**: There seems to be some confusion in the OP and various responses, so let's make it super clear for Python 2 users:

1. Add `google-cloud-bigquery` to `requirements.txt`
2. Create `appengine_config.py` to match that of [Step 4 on this page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#copying_a_third-party_library) (which you seem to have)
3. Delete the lines with `apiclient` or `googleapiclient` and `oauth2client` (wrong client libraries) from `main.py`
4. Run `pip2 install -t lib -r requirements.txt` (or just `pip` if you don't have Python 3 installed)
5. **NOTE**: Python 3 users don't have to play these games... step 1 above is all you need to do... no `appengine_config.py` file, no running `pip install`, and no `lib` folder.

For a broader audience, see [my answer to this more general question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67863189/305689).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use 3rd party libraries that are not included [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27) list, then you'll have to add them manually.

In order to include manually any other library you have to have them inside the directory where the app.yaml lives. So for example if you have the following structure:

```
hello
├── libs
│   └── bs4 
├── hello.py 
└── app.yaml
```

then in your hello.py you have to put these two lines in the beginning of the file:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'libs')
```

After doing that you'll be able to use any 3rd party library that you're going to put in that libs directory. For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: Thank you for your responses. 

@dan - I have tried this already in fact if you look at my screenshot of the appengine_config.py you will see it matches your suggestion.

bravin - I have tired this it doesn't actually work

Answer (score 0):

While @Bravin is on the right path the **recommended** procedure for [vendoring in 3rd party libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_third-party_library) is a bit different:

> 1. Create a directory to store your third-party libraries, such as `lib/`.
>
>    ```
>    mkdir lib
>    ```
> 2. Use [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) (version 6 or later) with the `-t <directory>` flag to copy the libraries into the folder you created in the previous step.
>      For example:
>
>    ```
>     pip install -t lib/ <library_name>
>    ```
>
>    [Using Homebrew Python on Mac OS X?](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#vendoring)
> 3. Create a file named `appengine_config.py` in the same folder as your `app.yaml` file.
> 4. Edit the `appengine_config.py` file and provide your library directory to the `vendor.add()` method.
>
>    ```
>    # appengine_config.py
>    from google.appengine.ext import vendor
>
>    # Add any libraries install in the "lib" folder.
>    vendor.add('lib')
>    ```

Comment: Thank you for your responses.